# Unknown meaning of a carving on the back of a Buddha statue (Character identified: 朱)

Tags: translation, meaning, character-identification

I hope someone could help me understand if this is something. Its on a Budddha statue I purchased.

[image]

Comment: Either seal script for 朱 or decorative variant of 壽, I hope someone who knows more about buddha statues can comment.

Answer (score 1):

It's 朱

In 篆文: 
[image]

It is a common surname in Chinese, originally refers to inner red wood.

> 說文解字注: 朱本木名。引伸假借爲純赤之字。糸部曰。絑、純赤也。是其本字也。

For variations you can find here : http://www.guoxuedashi.com/zixing/yanbian/4472tv/